# script_content\main_files\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php:118

Tags: laravel

When I added a new admin in admin list then I was login with new admin  it was  open but  if added some product or property so I get some error-: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

also get error Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling yo what's wrong :  `htmlspecialchars()` expects string but object given. I believe probably somewhere in your code within a `blade` file, You used an object in `{{}}` instead of a string.

Comment: okay but when I used old admin login so its work very well

Comment: and with new admin login so there is  create problem with the htmlspecialchars() expects string but object given.

Comment: edit your question and add your controller and the view in create section

Comment: problem is not solve